# How can I refresh new values added to my form after a submission

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a few hidden fields and I want to fill them with values after I submit.
but once the submit has been called all the values from the form, it seems like, are stored internally. So even if I try and do a jquery call to put a new value in the hidden field, it doesn't pass it as a parameter in the server call to the controller.

ex.

```js
$("#navbarForm").off('submit').on('submit', function (event) {

  $("#hiddenField").val('someValue');
  
  });
```

Comment: can you provide the HTML you are using? it will give more clarity

Comment: I just want to know if there's a way to reload a form with new values after I catch it with .submit() in jquery?

Comment: let me put it this way, you want to add some data to hidden fields and submit the form after button click?

Comment: Did you mean do you want to put a value on hidden fields if the button is clicked? Try putting a value on the field first before submitting the form

Comment: No, the form is being submitted by pressing the return button (it's a text field for a search). When the user presses the return button and the form is submitted, there is a little extra computing I need to perform and I need to then put that extra bit of info in a hidden field.

Comment: I think you can't do that since the page is being refreshed after the form has been submitted. Try to store the value you want on localStorage then put it on the hidden field onpageload

Comment: huh ok, I though there might be a way to reload the form or something so that if I updated values they would be passed on to the server.